# Proving a specific subset of the rationals is not equal to the empty set.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

How would I prove that for any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\{t \in \mathbb{Q}|t \lt q\} \neq \{\}$?

I have written the following:

$\{t \in \mathbb{Q}|x \lt q\}$ is the set of all rational numbers less than some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. Since the set of rationals is infinite, for any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ we are guarranteed to have some $t \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $t \lt q$. Therefore $\{t \in \mathbb{Q}|t \lt q\} \neq \{\}$.

Is this appropriate justification? I'm a bit unsure about it because my real analysis course has not said anything about the rationals being an infinite set yet.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct if you only use that it is an infinite set.

You could try the following, if $q=n/m$ with $q\neq 0$, then $2^{-\text{sign}(q)}q\in \mathbb{Q}$ is the $t$ you are looking for.

Comment: Simpler is to put $t=q-1$ and note that $t<q.$

Comment: This makes perfect sense. This is because it is just an 
existential proof right?

Comment: Yes, that construction is valid too!